# HP E3800 Static Trunks

Tags: ieee-802.1ax

I am new to HP networking and have a question about the correct Syntax for static trunks.

I have 2 x E3800 switches Mesh stacked, connected to those are 24 x E2530 layer 2 switches. Each 2530 has two links back to the 3800s i.e. Switch 1 interface 22 is connected to 1/1 and 23 is connected to 2/1 and i want to aggregate those links using a static aggregated link.

At the moment I have configured trunks like this:

```
trunk 23-24 trk23 lacp
```

and on the 3800:

```
trunk 1/1, 2/1 trk1 lacp
```

After doing a bit of reading i think that's actually creating a Dynamic trunk?

Should i be using:

```
trunk 23-24 trk23 trunk
```

Thanks

Dave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  `LACP` creates a dynamic trunk. `trunk` makes a static (no protocol) trunk.